# How to delete all the content of a list A without deleting the content of a list of lists that contains the list A.?

Tags: java, list

I'm having a problem trying to clear a list and use it again.

I have the following text and it is divided into multiple words in a list:
"Hi, this text is a sample. Hello again, this is another text."

What I need to do is concatenate the elements of the list until I find the word "text" and then save the indexes of the list in another list. Then clear the list, concatenate again until the word "text" appears and save the new indexes. I used the clean () method to clean the list, but the list of lists is also cleaned.

The output of my list of lists is an empty list:

```
Hi, this text is a sample. 
List of index: [0, 1, 2, 3]

Hello again, this is another text.
List of index: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

List of Lists: [[], []]
```

What I need is the following:

```
Hi, this text is a sample. 
List of index: [0, 1, 2, 3]

Hello again, this is another text.
List of index: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

List of Lists: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

This is my code:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {
            {
                add("Hi, ");                //0
                add("th");                  //1
                add("is ");                 //2
                add("text is a sample. ");  //3
                add("Hello ag");            //4
                add("ain, ");               //5
                add("this i");              //6
                add("s an");                //7
                add("other ");              //8
                add("text.");               //9
            }
        };
        
        
        String tmpText="";
        List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<List> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List>();
        
        for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++) {
            tmpText = tmpText + list.get(i);
            indexList.add(i);
            if(tmpText.contains("text")) {
                System.out.println(tmpText);
                System.out.println("List of index: "+indexList + "\n");
                listOfLists.add(indexList);
                tmpText="";
                indexList.clear();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("List of Lists: "+listOfLists);
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this statement `indexList.clear();` with `indexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();`